# creating site in cq5 siteadmin using geometrix Blueprint is right or not?

Tags: aem

I am developing an application using cq5,I have to create a site,when I am going to create a site I need to select a Blue Print. I have selected geometrix Blue Print for the same.
I don't know if this method is right or not? 
Please tell me is there any other way to create a new project/site in site admin.

Thanks in advance

actually I want to have JCR:Content of my parent page same as the below jcr:content.
Please tell me how can I create the parent page same as the  parent page of geometrix outdoor site?Please tell me ASAP.
[image: image of jcr:content]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that what you are trying to do is not correct. Blueprinting is a special function, used with Multi Site Manager and trying to create a new site using it will not get you what you want. Of course, I'm assuming you're trying to do more than create a copy of Geometrixx.

This can be a point of confusion for someone new to Adobe Experience Manager (CQ5). There technically is not entity called a "site". Instead, in the Site Administration UI, you just have a hierarchical collection of "pages". Those pages generally follow a convention-based grouping that acts as the "site". For example, /content/geometrixx is "the site" and /en is the homepage for the English version of it. Make sense?

You need to remember that AEM is a platform for managing web content, not an application. In other words, you necessarily customize it to create your site. Before you can create your site, you'll need (at a minimum) a new template/page component that adheres to your site's branding/layout/etc. and allows inclusion of other components. You'll likely have custom components, but to start, the foundation ones will do fine.

Reference the Adobe documentation for details about how to build that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,But this is not the complete information that I want ,please read the question again I have modified it.Kindly help if possible.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you are trying to do. Are you just experimenting with the Geometrixx site? You can create another "site" (see my last comment), by going to /content and creating a new page. Just select whatever template you want, because you'll generally make that page redirect to /content/whatever/en. I assume you have already built a template/page component that you would select.